# More functional and concise way to write this in Scala

Tags: scala

I started with this (in a Play Action method):

```
    val foo = JPA.em.find(classOf[Foo], id)
    if (foo == null) NotFound("Bad Id") else Ok(Json.toJson(foo))
```

not like its imperativeness, I went to this:

```
    Option(JPA.em.find(classOf[Foo], id)) match {
      case Some(foo) => Ok(Json.toJson(foo))
      case None => NotFound("Bad Id")
    }
```

more functional, but longer.

I apologize for the very general nature of the question but I bet the answers could be helpful to many.

Comment: I'm not sure "more functional" and "concise" as criteria are hard and fast enough for a SO question. *Maybe* [codereview.se] but I'm not familiar with that site's policies and whether "I have this code, make it better" questions are specific enough for it.

Comment: That said, your latter example looks more like paying lip service to FP conventions than being actually functional in any meaningful way. I'd stick with the first one and worry about where the advantages of FP matter (e.g. composability of actual functions), as opposed to obsessing over single statements. It's kind of like trying to make code "more objecty" by replacing methods with an `ICallable` interface throughout.

Comment: The point wasn't to make this particular code snippet better, but to just understand how it can be done in general.

Comment: BTW, I know my example was doing nothing more than paying lip service to FP, which is why I posted the question. :)

Comment: See this for many more ways to cut out the boilerplate of matching on Options: http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Option(JPA.em.find(classOf[Foo], id)).map(foo=>Ok(Json.toJson(foo))).getOrElse(NotFound("Bad Id"))
```

Comment: Since 2.10 there is also `Option.fold`, which is both `map` and `getOrElse` in one method.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely worth wrapping unsafe Java APIs like this with some reusable methods that return `Option`s, for example

```
def findOpt[T](cls: Class[T], id: Object): Option[T] =
  Option(JPA.em.find(cls, id))
```

Consuming this API, instead of using JPA directly, means that you don't need to worry about null checks elsewhere in your code. It's all dealt with in one place.

Now, you can decide whether to use `match`, or `fold`, or `map`/`getOrElse`; what's important is that the possible absence of a result is represented in the type of `findOpt`.

```
findOpt(classOf[Foo], id) map (foo => OK(Json.toJson(foo)) getOrElse NotFound("Bad Id")
```

Comment: IF the purpose is to propogate the result and handle it at multiple in the code, then YES it's worth wrapping in `Option`.  If it's a simple one-time check, as suggested by the question, then I stand by my response (below/above).